# gemが上手く使用できない

Tags: ruby, rubygems

初心者なので質問におかしな点があるかもしれませんが御容赦ください。

以下のgemを使用としたのですが上手くいきません。
https://github.com/craysiii/binance

cloud9では以下のやり方で上手くいったのですが、PCにrubyをインストールし、実行したら上手くいきません。

```
require 'binance'
require 'eventmachine'

puts client.ping
```

PCはwindowsでruby2.4.4です。gem listの中に使用したいgemは入っているのは確認できるのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
    C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.4/rubyeventmachine (LoadError)
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・
```

一応以下のサイトを参考にeventmachineをアンインストールし、--platform rubyをつけてインストールし直したのですが、やはりうまくいきません。
https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/806

私の知識不足・検索不足は重々承知ですが、教えて頂けると幸いです。

追記
以下が--platform rubyをつけてインストールした際のエラーコードです。

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180929-2192-1nwhkk4.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lcrypto... no
checking for -lssleay32... no
checking for -lcrypto... no
checking for -lssleay32... no
checking for -lcrypto... no
checking for -lssleay32... no
checking for -lcrypto... no
checking for -lssleay32... no
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... no
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... no
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for -lkernel32... no
could not find library: kernel32
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-ssl-dir
        --without-ssl-dir
        --with-ssl-include
        --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
        --with-ssl-lib
        --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
        --with-openssl-config
        --without-openssl-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-ssleay32lib
        --without-ssleay32lib
        --with-ssl-dir
        --without-ssl-dir
        --with-ssl-include
        --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
        --with-ssl-lib
        --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-ssleay32lib
        --without-ssleay32lib
        --with-ssl-dir
        --without-ssl-dir
        --with-ssl-include
        --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
        --with-ssl-lib
        --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-ssleay32lib
        --without-ssleay32lib
        --with-ssl-dir
        --without-ssl-dir
        --with-ssl-include
        --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
        --with-ssl-lib
        --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-ssleay32lib
        --without-ssleay32lib
        --with-kernel32lib
        --without-kernel32lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out
```

追記2
返信遅れて申し訳わりません。
ridk versionの結果は以下です。

```
---
ruby:
  path: C:/Ruby24-x64
  version: 2.4.4
  platform: x64-mingw32
ruby_installer:
  package_version: 2.4.4-2
  git_commit: 513abb8
msys2:
  path: C:\Ruby24-x64\msys64
cc: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 8.2.0
sh: GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.19(3)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
os: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

windowsは7です。

Comment: インストールしたRubyはRubyInstallerのRuby+Devkit 2.4.4-2 (x64)であっていますか？インストール後に`ridk install`を実行しましたか？--platform rubyを付けてインストールするときにエラー等のメッセージは表示されませんでしたか？最後に、`gem list eventmachine`と実行したときの結果を教えてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ridk installは行っています。gem list eventmachineの結果は{*** LOCAL GEMS ***  eventmachine (1.2.7 x64-mingw32)}です。ruby -vでは{ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x64-mingw32]}です。

Comment: もう一度アンインストール、--platform rubyをつけてインストールを実行したところ以下のエラーが出てきました。ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.    current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180929-6912-qnd2re.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lcrypto... no・・・と以降のcheckingは全てnoでした。

Comment: 最初に試したときはちゃんとアンインストールが出来ていなかったと思われます。その次は、gemインストール時のコンパイルが失敗しているのでインストール自体が出来ていません。原因を探るために、--platform rubyでインストールを実行したときのエラーログ全てを省略せずに**質問**に追加してください。質問は「編集」の所からいつでも変更できます。

Comment: エラーメッセージで出ているkernel32はWindows OSに含まれているDLLの事ですので、本来なら見つからないとなることはないはずの物です。私の手元の環境では再現できず、なぜそんなエラーになるのかもわかりません。Windowsのバージョンと`ridk version`の実行結果なども追加してください。同じような環境で同様の現象を確認し、解決手段がわかる人が出てくるかも知れません。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。また自分でも調べてみようと思います。